# add_library works but find_library unable to find the library

Tags: android-studio, cmake

I'm working on a C++ library built with cmake. It's being used in console applications and Android apps. When I build it in Android Studio I am able to add the libraries it depends on using `add_library()`. Since it is being used in multiple Android apps with different directory structures I am trying to use `find_library()` so I can list multiple places where the library will be found in my single project.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project(ModernTimeStretch)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_library(ModernTimeStretch SHARED
        ..
        )

 if (NOT ANDROID_ABI)
    # Find libav with PkgConfig
else ()
    set(LIBAV_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libav/${ANDROID_ABI})

    #This doesn't work
    find_library(avcodec
            NAMES "libavcodec.so" libavcodec.so avcodec
            PATHS ${LIBAV_DIR} LIBAV_DIR "LIBAV_DIR"
            )

   #[[
   This works!
   add_library(avcodec SHARED IMPORTED)

    set_property(TARGET avcodec PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${LIBAV_DIR}/libavcodec.so")
]]
    
    target_link_libraries(ModernTimeStretch
            avcodec
            ..
            )
endif (NOT ANDROID_ABI)
```

How can I make `find_library()` work so I can add another variable like `LIBAV_DIR2` to the PATHS part of `find_library()`?

Comment: What do you mean by "This doesn't work" when describe `find_library` case? Do you check `avcodec` variable and find it to be NOTFOUND? Or what?

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes, variable not defined

Comment: Hm, being equal to `NOTFOUND` doesn't mean that variable is "not defined". Anyway, how do you check that the variable is not defined? I don't see a checking part in the code you provided. Usually, a result of `find_library` call is checked with `if (NOT avcodec)` command. Also, for use result of `find_library` in the `target_link_libraries` call, you need to **dereference** a variable: `target_link_libraries(ModernTimeStretch ${avcodec} ...)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev is spot on. I had made the very same mistake long time ago.